# Effectively measure execution time of multi-threaded sorting

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

I am working on an assignment for my C# class and the task is to sort a set of 8 lists with around 1 million entries using both multi-threading and a single thread. My single thread function is fully working and runs with an average execution time of ~750ms.

It is my understanding that multi-threading should make this process run much faster however my average time of execution of my implementation is ~650ms. Example execution times were given (obviously they will not be the same) however the ratio of Multi Execution/Single is 6. As such I believe am running into a (possible) issue with my implementation.

I declare my initial thread:

```
Thread multiThreaded = new Thread(() => singleListSortWorker(data2));
        multiThreaded.Start();
```

So this will call the singleListSortWorker function below

```
private void singleListSortWorker(List<List<int>> lists)
    {
        Stopwatch s = new Stopwatch();
        s.Start();

        List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();

        foreach(var list in lists)
        {
            Thread t = new Thread(() => doSortOnSingleList(list));
            threads.Add(t);
            t.Start();

        }
        foreach(var thread in threads)
        {
            thread.Join();
        }
        s.Stop();
        //SetTextBox2 is a thread safe function used to set the text in my field
        SetTextBox2("Multi-Threaded sort: " + s.Elapsed.Milliseconds + "ms." + System.Environment.NewLine);
    }
```

As you can see it is starting a new thread for each list with the following function:

```
private void doSortOnSingleList(List<int> list)
    {
        list.Sort();
    }
```

So essentially I am creating a thread that spawns a new thread for each list, joining each to make sure that execution is measured properly and then finishes.

Is there an issue with my implementation or is this a relatively decent way of doing this?

Comment: Use a profiler. Stopwatch wont tell you where the bottleneck is.

Comment: Do you have an eight-core CPU? If not, then trying to sort 8 lists simultaneously is more likely to slow things down than speed things up. Without a lot more detail, including [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the behavior, and details on your exact machine configuration (at a minimum, the exact CPU model, and preferably also details like the OS version, .NET version, and even the amount of RAM), no good, specific answer can be provided.